# How to share a project on Microsoft Custom Translator (https://portal.customtranslator.azure.ai)

Tags: microsoft-translator

I am working on a training a translation system using the Microsoft Custom Translator. However, I need to be able to share it with other members of my organization. How would I go about sharing a project with another member of my organization?

Thanks,
Tymoore Jamal

Answer (score 1):

Currently, we do not support project sharing with other users.  This is a feature we are working on and plan to ship when Custom Translator comes out of preview and is released.

Comment: Do you have any estimate of when this will occur?

Comment: We are planning to release in October.